# Verificar se um usuário já ativou a sua conta por e-mail, caso contrário lembra-lo de ativar

Tags: otimização

estou desenvolvendo uma rede corporativa, e gostaria de fazer a verificação toda vez que o usuário logou, se ele ativou ou não sua conta través do `token` enviado para seu e-mail. Mas eu não gostaria que essa verificação fosse feita o tempo todo, isso é possível?

Por exemplo, enquanto o usuário não ativar sua conta, o sistema vai ficar verificando se a flag no banco de dados "ativou" está como `true`, mas após ela ficar como `true`, nunca mais essa conta precisaria ser verificada novamente, pois já foi ativada.

Independente da tecnologia (linguagem) utilizada, gostaria de saber se é computacionalmente possível, através de alguma lógica, criar um algoritmo que fosse utilizado até determinado parâmetro ter sido atendido, e depois disso aquele código "não passaria mais a ser executado" (seria descartado do código -fonte, algo do tipo). Porque ele depende de uma particularidade que precisa ser verificada, mas uma vez verificada como `true` não seria necessário mais possuir esse trecho de código, porém cada usuário tem sua verificação de token particular, não poderia simplesmente remover do código esse trecho, pois em algum momento um ou outro usuário precisaria da verificação.

Adiando que não é algo trivial, é mais conceitual, se é possível ou não, independente da linguagem utilizada.

Comment: Mas que tecnologia, linguagem voce esta trabalhando, acredito que falta mais detalhes para agente começar a pensar se podemos te ajudar em algo!

Comment: Sim, é possível e depende um pouco de como sua aplicação foi desenvolvida e também da linguagem.

Comment: Olá, @AlexandreC.Caus, independente da tecnologia (linguagem) utilizada, gostaria de saber se é computacionalmente possível, através de alguma lógica, criar um algoritmo que fosse utilizado até determinado parâmetro ter sido atendido, e depois disso aquele código não passaria mais a ser executado. Porque ele depende de uma particularidade que precisa ser verificada, mas uma vez verificada como true não seria necessário mais fazê-la.

Comment: A têm sim, eu gosto de usar delphi, você já viu falar? É uma beleza, é aplicação desktop, e a curva de aprendizagem é menor que as demais(java, c..).. É fácil de fazer a interface, tem uma boa IDE..

Comment: Basicamente, se o código está lá, ele vai ser executado, não tem como fugir. As soluções são: forçar a aplicação re-escrever aquela parte do código (se for web é fácil, se for desktop é complicado), mas isso teria o problema de deixá-lá inútil para novos usuários, caso precise de um "CTRL + C, CTRL + V", ou criar uma outra condição que impeça a verificação, e nesse segundo caso, ela ainda iria continuar rodando a condição, mas não seria atendida. A vantagem da segunda condição é que como você vai rodar a aplicação em uma rede corporativa, não vai ter que verificar na rede.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira é quase isso da segunda opção, só que estou pensando em algo do tipo da resposta do António campos, mas voltada para o "log-in", como uma rede corporativa (similar a uma rede social) possui muitas consultas, queria evitar fazer essa verificação o tempo todo via consulta no banco, mas quando o usuário faz log-in é obrigatório fazer uma consulta no banco, nesse momento eu posso recuperar a variável "ativou" e passar ela via GET para evitar consultas, otimizando o código, o que acham?

Comment: Isto deve ocorrer toda vez que o usuário logar, ou apenas uma vez na vida de cada usuário?

Comment: Justamente isso @GuilhermeNascimento, só vai ocorrer uma vez na vida de cada usuário.

Comment: Não sei se o titulo ficou bom, mas acho que agora tem mais sentido.

Comment: Na verdade, seria evitar de ficar repetindo uma verificação uma vez que a mesma já foi atendida! mas acho que ficou legal! Criei a mesma pergunta no StackEn e gostei da resposta do cara, foi mais ou menos assim: "Se você depende de uma flag para verificar se o usuário está ativo, não tem como deixar de fazer essa verificação, o que pode ser feito é otimizar essa verificação logo na autenticação do usuário". Valeu pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica será algo do gênero:

Na base de dados na tabela de usuário, o campo, por exemplo, `user_ative=false` e  quando o usuário ativar a conta muda para o `user_ative` para `true`...

Durante o `log-in` do usuário, você recupera na mesma `query`, se possível (a depender da sua estrutura de dados, se o campo estiver na mesma tabela do usuário), e com isso passa esse parâmetro via `GET`, `POST` ou `SESSION` para evitar realizar novas consultas em outras páginas para fazer a verificação, pois não é possível para vários usuários se ter diferentes códigos-fonte, o que impossibilita a ideia de um algoritmo ser executado uma única vez na vida útil daquele usuário.

Comment: Não é bem isso Antonio, é justamente pelo fato de eu não querer ficar fazendo essa verificação o tempo todo, que não gostaria de colocá-la para ser sempre feita.

Comment: No processo de login... verifica isso, e só deixa entrar se já tiver a conta activa... quando valida o utilizador e password valida também se a conta está ativa... se tem tudo numa tabela ao fazer select para obter faça algo do género  `select * from utilizador where username =?? and password = ?? and user_active=true;`

Comment: @MaiconHerverton, mas depende também viu. Fica difícil pra gente porque você não especificou como será a aplicação, e dificilmente existe um modelo que seja aplicável em todos os casos. Vamos supor que sua aplicação tenha um formulário de login, você poderia muito bem fazer do jeito que o Antonio disse, e o impacto no desempenho nem seria notado, afinal a conexão com o banco já vai ser feita, basta rodar mais uma query e se souber fazer, nem isso precisa. Qual o impacto de uma query no desempenho de uma aplicação local onde terá poucos usuários? Em contra partida, tentar fazer com que ela não

Comment: verifique, pode te levar a uma "gambiarra" que vai causar mais perda de desempenho ainda

Comment: O problema António, é que o usuário tem acesso a página "principal", e nela é que verifico se ele é ativo ou não, pois, caso ele não esteja ativo vou indicar um "link" para "reenviar" o token. Mas se ele estiver ativo, nunca mais essa verificação seria necessária entendeu. Mas acho que a única solução será seguir por essa questão de validação logo no log-in, mesmo que eu deixe o usuário "passar" para próxima página, ele existe, só não tem privilégios até confirmar sua conta via e-mail (token).

Comment: Na verdade @ClaydersonFerreira é uma rede corporativa, mas é Web semelhante ao facebook, plus e etc.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta do @AntónioCampos, pois ela seria a "mais lógica" possível dentro do conceito de programação no geral.